# How to deploy google function from google SDK from local system runtime python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to deploy Google Cloud Function from local system using the `gcloud` command-line tool.

My files are compressed in a .zip file. As described in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2t9w.png) the zip file contains **main.py** and **requirement.txt**

**main.py**  *(took from web for testing)*

```
from wand.image import Image
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
         'C:\\Users\\an20086686\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\deploy\\****-*****-poc-e4b410a65986.JSON')
THUMBNAIL_BUCKET = 'a_demo_storage_trigger1'
def make_thumbnail(data, context):

    bucket = client.get_bucket(data['****_my-awesome-bucket'])
    blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
    imagedata = blob.download_as_string()

    newimage = Image(blob=imagedata)
    newimage.sample(200,200)

    bucket = client.get_bucket(THUMBNAIL_BUCKET)
    newblob = bucket.blob('thumbnail-' + data['name'])     
    newblob.upload_from_string(newimage.make_blob())
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud-storage
Wand
```

Using the command below to deploy this function:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy make_thumbnail --runtime python37 \
--trigger-bucket ****_my-awesome-bucket \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

> Error 1 : (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments:
>   google.storage.object.finalize

When I use:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy make_thumbnail --runtime python37 \
--trigger-bucket ****_my-awesome-bucket \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,message=Function failed on loading user code.
>
> Error message: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist

Log of the encountered error:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMPU2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial doesn't use a ZIP file.

If you want to use a ZIP file, you'd need to specify it with the `--source` option. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--source).

And not sure if this is a typo in your question, but there needs to be a space before `--trigger-event`.

Answer (score 1):

As @YaguraStation mentioned the issue is because of the ZIP file. Let me give a bit more of an explanation though.

If you are following this documentation,[*Deploying from Your Local Machine*](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem), in order to deploy your function with the `gcloud` command your files should not be compressed in a ***ZIP*** file.

Your command somehow should look like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy make_thumbnail --runtime python37 \
--trigger-resource ****_my-awesome-bucket \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

> Note: ***RUNTIME*** and ***TRIGGER*** are two different values.

If you want to deploy a function and your files to be compressed into a ***ZIP*** file then add the `--source` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source):

```
gcloud functions deploy make_thumbnail --runtime python37 \
--trigger-resource ****_my-awesome-bucket \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize \
--source gs://path/to_file/file.zip
```

I tested both of the commands above and they are working for me as intended.